# How to select the current Divs ID name, Width and Height property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In here I have four divs with different width, heights and colors which show up and hide on respective button clicks. I am adding a class "activeDiv" to the div which shows so that I could select it with that selector. The point is - I want to select the current div's width, height and id name and store it so that I could use for further purposes rather than manually selecting them with selectors every time.When I tried the script alerts "null" and I have no clue what to do. Find the fiddle link below.

Thanks is advance for help.

Comment: oh! if the fiddle link did not show up here it is http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/pnhxxcsw/11/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/pnhxxcsw/12/

Comment: Just to prove a point, your entire code could be two lines instead -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pnhxxcsw/13/

Comment: thanks adeneo..I am starting off with scripting...but that was great in 2 lines.. i knew there was a pro way of doing it. but how I am figuring out now after having a look at your code. And by the way "can i expect a little explanation on the code u have posted" thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){

   // Selecting the Current Div Width, Height and Id Name
   var currentDivWidth = $('.activeDiv').width();
   var currentHeight = $('.activeDiv').height();
   var currentDivId = $('.activeDiv').attr('id');

   alert($('.activeDiv').width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it

```
var div = $('div').not(':first').hide().end();

$('button').on('click', function()  { 
    var current = div.hide().eq($(this).index()).show();

    var id     = current.prop('id');
    var height = current.height();
    var width  = current.width();

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pnhxxcsw/14/)

Comment: Could you tell me "div.hide().eq($(this).index()).show();" how does that work. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You only set your variable once before the active class exists, and you never update it when you click, so the variable never gets set.

If you try something like this it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/9ysez54j/

In your click functions:

```
$('body').trigger('updateCurrent');
```

And then you can have something like this:

```
$('body').on('updateCurrent', function() {
    // Selecting the Current Div Width, Height and Id Name
    var currentDivWidth = $('.activeDiv').width();
    var currentHeight = $('.activeDiv').height();
    var currentDivId = $('.activeDiv').attr('id');
    alert(currentDivId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue the other day. Let me try to explain this;
You are selecting divs with a class that does not exist yet. Therefore you need to select the div after the class has been appended. Not a perfect solution, but it may get you on your way.

```
function getWidth(currentDiv){
    var currentDivWidth = $(currentDiv).width();
    var currentHeight = $(currentDiv).height();
    var currentDivId = $(currentDiv).attr('id');
    alert(currentDivWidth);
}
//1.Hiding and Showing dive on button click
//2.Adding up a class "activeDiv" to the current Div so that I could select the current div with that class selector

$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#red').show().addClass('activeDiv');
    $('#green').hide();
    $('#yellow').hide();
    $('#blue').hide();  
    getWidth($('#red'));
});
```